# Loaded transformer. Unclear origin of formula

Tags: transformer, homework

From a homework task.

Given: nominal input $$U_{1N}$$ and nominal current output $$I_{2N}$$
Also given: output voltage without load $$U_{20}$$ and short circuit voltage $$U_{KN}$$
As for nominal values assume only ohmic loads.

The missing value is the loaded output voltage $$U_{2N}$$.

My prof used the formula $$U_{2N}=\sqrt{U_{20}^2 - (U_{20}\cdot U_{KN})^2}$$

It is clear that the squared formula is due to the fact that there's a right triangle in the vector diagram of which the unloaded output voltage is the hypothenuse and the nominal output voltage is one leg. But I don't understand where the product from unloaded voltage and short circuit voltage comes from.

Comment: A short circuit voltage is nothing else other than 0 volts so, something is wrong or needs explaining in your question.

Comment: Internal equivalent impedance = Ukn / I2n.

Comment: @Andyaka Short circuit voltage is by definition the primary voltage which can be measured when the secondary contacts are shorted and nominal current is flowing. This "short circuit voltage" can be found on most boiler plates of power transformers.

Comment: And generally, (if I remember well ...), the "short-circuit impedance" ... was "inductive" ...

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Should have read everything thoroughly.

The short circuit voltage is given in percent of the unloaded output voltage. Which again is common practice. On boiler plates of transformers the short circuit voltage is a percent value.

Then the multiplication starts to make sense. Otherwise the units in this formula cannot match.